# Can you give example of unbounded sequence with convergent subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My friends have found ($x_n$) =tan(n$\pi$/180) with subsequence tan (n$\pi$), but i still curious. Can you give another one?

Comment: $1,2,1,3,1,4,\ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example take your favourite sequence $y_n$ with $y_n \to \infty$, p.e. $y_n = n$ and let 
$$ x_n = \bigl(1 + (-1)^n\bigr)y_n $$
Then $x_{2n} = 2y_{2n} \to \infty$ and $x_{2n+1} = 0$, hence $(x_{2n})$ is unbounded, therefore $(x_n)$ is, and $(x_{2n+1})$ is convergent.

Comment: Great. It was simple example but i overlook on it. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n \rightarrow c $

Let $b_n \rightarrow \infty $

Let $c_{2n}=a_n $ and $c_{2n+1} = b_n $

{$c_i $} is unbound but its even terms converge to $c $.